# Do waste rocks have an utility?

Tags: surviving-mars

Do waste rocks have an utility (late-game)? Is there something to do with huge stacks of them?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, there is a tech called **Wasterock Liquefication** in engineering. It allows drones to convert waste rock to concrete. In my game it was very late (third to last tech in the row), but it pretty much instantly produced over 2000 concrete and cleared most of my dumping piles.

Answer (score 6):

Besides being able to make concrete from it using **Wasterock Liquefication** as described in [Dulkan's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/329558/23959), waste rock is used in building ramps and flattening uneven terrain.

In the "Green Planet" DLC, the Carbonate Processor consumes waste rock to improve the atmosphere.